# Compiling sources with a non-default compiler

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, debian

I need to implement an authentication scheme on an embedded device and require [gmp](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-announce/2014-March/000042.html) in order to perform large integer operations.
After downloading the sources they must be compiled with a proprietary version of compile tools in order to be able to statically link libraries(only one binary can be uploaded onto the controller at a time). 
After running configure the [following](http://paste.debian.net/277909/) make file is produced.

Running make with the proprietary compiler

```
make CC=/home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc
```

gives the following errors:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0/mpn'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`    -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c
libtool: compile:  /home/TI/ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/arm-none-eabi/bin/gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_fib_table -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -c fib_table.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fib_table.o
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [fib_table.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0/mpn'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/TI_workspace/gmp-6.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

cc1 is located in:

```
$ sudo find . -name cc1 -print
./ccsv5/tools/compiler/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.3/cc1
```

Is it possible to generate a makefile so that it uses the proprietary tool chain instead of the default one? If yes, how should it be configured?

**Edit:**

Bellow are the ./configure options:

```
$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures GNU MP 6.0.0 to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/gmp]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

Program names:
  --program-prefix=PREFIX            prepend PREFIX to installed program names
  --program-suffix=SUFFIX            append SUFFIX to installed program names
  --program-transform-name=PROGRAM   run sed PROGRAM on installed program names

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-maintainer-mode  enable make rules and dependencies not useful
              (and sometimes confusing) to the casual installer
  --enable-assert         enable ASSERT checking [[default=no]]
  --enable-alloca         how to get temp memory [[default=reentrant]]
  --enable-cxx            enable C++ support [[default=no]]
  --enable-assembly       enable the use of assembly loops [[default=yes]]
  --enable-fft            enable FFTs for multiplication [[default=yes]]
  --enable-old-fft-full   enable old mpn_mul_fft_full for multiplication
                          [[default=no]]
  --enable-nails          use nails on limbs [[default=no]]
  --enable-profiling      build with profiler support [[default=no]]
  --enable-fat            build a fat binary on systems that support it
                          [[default=no]]
  --enable-minithres      choose minimal thresholds for testing [[default=no]]
  --enable-fake-cpuid     enable GMP_CPU_TYPE faking cpuid [[default=no]]
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-readline         readline support in calc demo program
                          [[default=detect]]
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-sysroot=DIR Search for dependent libraries within DIR
                        (or the compiler's sysroot if not specified).

Some influential environment variables:
  ABI         desired ABI (for processors supporting more than one ABI)
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CC_FOR_BUILD
              build system C compiler
  CPP_FOR_BUILD
              build system C preprocessor
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
  M4          m4 macro processor
  YACC        The `Yet Another Compiler Compiler' implementation to use.
              Defaults to the first program found out of: `bison -y', `byacc',
              `yacc'.
  YFLAGS      The list of arguments that will be passed by default to $YACC.
              This script will default YFLAGS to the empty string to avoid a
              default value of `-d' given by some make applications.

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proprietary toolchain"? That is apparently gcc, noting close source. I just wonder why not just install gcc-arm-none-eabi, binutils, etc. from a package? I use the original Ubuntu packages (on Kubuntu), but there is also a ppa with more recent versions maintained by ARM developers. If there is no native for Debian (not sure, but Ubuntu is actually based on Debian), try the Ubuntu ppa.

Comment: @Olaf It's a Texas Instruments tool chain. I couldn't get any binaries on the controller without using code composer(compile and flash).

Comment: That is nonsense! It is gcc, nothing proprietary. You just need the TI libs. For JTAG use OpenOCD (also quite likely a package) with a proper configuration. It's just the IDE which might be proprietary; no need for that, use Code::Blocks, Eclipse (if you think to require that bloat) or a simple editor and console. However, as that is provided by TI, there should be information provided how to make it run. Why not ask in TI forum?

Comment: ISn't there some kind of `configure` script? It is often accepting the `host` or `target` parameter where you can pass your toolchain prefix.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh. I've added the configure flags. I don't see where exactly should the toolchain prefix be added.

Comment: Can you compile a standalone 'hello world' program using the alternative tool-chain?  Normally, an error like 'cannot find cc1' means there is a configuration problem in that alternative tool-chain.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler. No, still can't find cc. Where should I start looking for the problem?